# Ruby on Rails 4 : sorting nested attributes

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using nested attributes to update parent and children in one form, and I would like to have children sorted accroding to their source_caption field:

```
...
<!-- Loop with details mappings data to update -->

  <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
    <tr align="left">
  <th>Software</th>
  <th>Table</th>
  <th>Value</th>
  <th>Value</th>
  <th>Table</th>
  <th>Software</th>
    </tr>
    <%= f.fields_for :mappings do |m| %>
    <tr align="left">
    <td><%= m.text_field :source_software, :readonly => true %></td>
    <td><%= m.text_field :source_table, :readonly => true %></td>
    <td><%= m.text_field :source_caption, :readonly => true %></td>
    <td><%= m.collection_select :target_code, @target_values, :value_code, :value_caption %></td>
    <td><%= m.text_field :target_table, :readonly => true %></td>
    <td><%= m.text_field :target_software, :readonly => true %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end%>
  </table>
...
```

By default, they are sorted regarding the last update date of the record.
How can I have them sorted by source_caption field ?

**UPDATE**

Controller calling the view: MappingListsController

```
# GET /mappings_list/1/edit
  def edit
      @mappings_list = MappingsList.pgnd(current_playground).find(params[:id])
  end
```

Model for Mapping

```
class Mapping < ActiveRecord::Base

### scope
  scope :pgnd, ->(my_pgnd) { where "playground_id=?", my_pgnd }

### before filter
before_update :retrieve_target_caption

### validation
...
validates :playground_id, presence: true
    belongs_to :playground
validates :playground, presence: true                       # validates that the playground exists
    belongs_to :mappings_list
belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "owner_id"        # helps retrieving the owner name

### private functions definitions
  private

  def retrieve_target_caption
    current_list = self.mappings_list.target_list
    current_value = current_list.values.where("value_code = ?", self.target_code).take! 
    self.target_caption = current_value.value_caption
  end

end
```

Model for MappingsList

```
class MappingsList < ActiveRecord::Base

### scope
  scope :pgnd, ->(my_pgnd) { where "playground_id=?", my_pgnd }

### before filter
  before_create :set_code

### after filter
  after_create :build_mappings

### validation
...
    validates :playground_id, presence: true
    belongs_to :playground
    validates :playground, presence: true                   # validates that the playground exists
belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "owner_id"    # helps retrieving the owner name
    belongs_to :source_list, :class_name => "ValuesList", :foreign_key => "source_list_id" # helps retrieving the source list name
    belongs_to :target_list, :class_name => "ValuesList", :foreign_key => "target_list_id" # helps retrieving the target list name
    has_many :mappings
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :mappings

### private functions definitions
  private

  ### before filters
    def set_code 
      self.code = "#{source_list.code}_TO_#{target_list.code}"
    end 

  ### after filters
    def build_mappings
      self.source_list.values.each do |mapping_value|
        self.mappings.build(:playground_id => self.playground_id, :source_software => mapping_value.values_list.software_name, :source_table => mapping_value.values_list.table_name, :source_code => mapping_value.value_code, :source_caption => mapping_value.value_caption, :target_software => self.target_list.software_name, :target_table => self.target_list.table_name, :created_by => self.created_by, :updated_by => self.updated_by)
      end
    end

end
```

**Note:** when a mapping list is created, it generates the mappings. Then the mapping list can be edited with its nested mappings.

Thanks for your help,

Best regards,

Fred

Comment: Please share the details of Parent and Child model and schema. Also, share the controller action from where you are passing the data to this view. Update the question itself.

Comment: Hi Kirti Thorat, any idea about sorting the nested attributes ? Thanks.